# Stop nodejs from garbage collection / automatic closing of File Descriptors

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, filesystems

Consider a database engine, which operates on an externally opened file - like SQLite, except the file handle is passed to its constructor. I'm using a setup like this for my app, but can't seem to figure out why NodeJS insists on closing the file descriptor after 2 seconds of operation. I need that thing to stay open!

```js
const db = await DB.open(await fs.promises.open('/path/to/db/file', 'r+'));
...
(node:100840) Warning: Closing file descriptor 19 on garbage collection
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:100840) [DEP0137] DeprecationWarning: Closing a FileHandle object on garbage collection is deprecated. Please close FileHandle objects explicitly using FileHandle.prototype.close(). In the future, an error will be thrown if a file descriptor is closed during garbage collection.
```

The class `DB` uses the provided file descriptors extensively, over an extended period of time, so it closing is rather annoying. In that class, I'm using methods such as `readFile`, `createReadStream()` and the `readline` module to step through the lines of the file. I'm passing `{ autoClose: false, emitClose: false }` to any read/write streams I'm using, but to no avail.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I stop it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `DB` object?  Which database?  This seems like perhaps the `db` variable goes out of scope and gets garbage collected so nothing is left that can use the database and thus it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Oh that's one I wrote myself. It's really just a class with a bunch of parsers build in that navigates a text file. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/J-Cake/b17b15305b61d9359a1f9f77712b525f)

Comment: I suspect you're running into an evil problem in using `await` in this `for await (const line of readline.createInterface({input: file.createReadStream({start: 0, autoClose: false})}))`.  If you use `await` anywhere else, the underlying stream fires all its `data` events and finishes and, in some cases, your process even exits before you got to process any of the data events.  IMO, it's a wretched design.

Comment: I've run into this problem myself and helped multiple other folks here who ran into the same issue.  Basically when you're using this asynchronous iterator on the stream, you can't use any other `await` or you will miss events on the stream.  I think the design needs to be fixed so that the stream doesn't fire events except in service of the `await` on the asyncIterator.

Comment: it's funny you should mention that, because I'm here detecting some weird formatting issues after the `commit()` method is called.

Comment: well thanks for the pointers. I'll play around with it, and let you know if that did it

Comment: FYI, it "might" work if you `.pause()` the stream at the top of the `for` loop and then `.resume()` it at the end of the `for` loop so that it won't fire `data` events while your other `await` statements are waiting.  Sometimes `.pause()` doens't stop all `data` events, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Okay, it looks like the `.pause()` approach didn't work. I guess I'm writing it with callbacks

Comment: For starters, `parseHeader()` is entirely synchronous so you can remove the `async` on it's function definition and then remove the `await` in front of the function call.

Comment: Similarly `parse()` doesn't need to be `async` either as it is entirely synchronous too, so you can remove the `async` designation and remove the `await` in front of it.  That should remove this particular asynchronous problem.  I don't know if that fixes the rest of your issue, but this one cause would be gone if there are no `await` statements in the loop.

Comment: oh dear I hand't even noticed that. I've made the changes (they're in the gist, in a second file). I'm now not using `for await` and nested `await` statements, yet the issue persists

Comment: looks like `process.on('exit', () => db.commit());` stops the warnings :/

Comment: Where are the changes in the gist?

Comment: They should be there. I've reuploaded them

Comment: OK, I see now.  You're using events now to iterate the lines.  That would certainly make that asyncIterator issue with streams go away.

Comment: It appears so, but I'm still noticing malformed data when I call `.commit()`

Comment: So it looks like your tips about the event-based streams were actually the key. It's functional now, and works as expected. If you wanted to write up a quick answer, I'll click accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're running into an evil problem in using `await` in this

```
for await (const line of readline.createInterface({input: file.createReadStream({start: 0, autoClose: false})}))
```

If you use `await` anywhere else in the `for` loop block (which you are), the underlying stream fires all its `data` events and finishes (while you are at the other `await` and, in some cases, your process even exits before you got to process any of the `data` or `line` events from the stream. This is a truly flawed design and has bitten many others.

The safest way around this is to not use the `asyncIterator` at all, and just wrap a promise yourself around the regular eveents from the readline object.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help @jfriend00. I wouldn't have been able to work that out myself.

Comment: @J-Cake - Yeah, I only knew about this one because it bit me in my own programming.  As far as I'm concerned, the readline asyncIterator is pretty much broken for anything beyond simple demo code.  The whole readline interface has always seemed messy to me.  Why in the world, you'd cram line by line reading of a file in the same interface as tty prompting, I have no idea.  And, clearly the asyncIterator was just bolted on without really thinking through the issues with doing that on top of a stream that is flowing.  They are incompatible models without a lot more code to control the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Close the file handle after waiting for any pending operation.

```
import { open } from 'fs/promises';

let filehandle;
try {
  filehandle = await open('thefile.txt', 'r');
} finally {
  await filehandle?.close();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't have worked as I needed the file to remain open for the duration of the Database connection, which is potentially indefinite. Thanks for your help regardless